# How to bootstrap angular in Jasmine to unit test adding directives/controllers after bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to figure out how to apply, angular.bootstrap within a Jasmine/Karma unit test suite, and I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

I have a need to lazy load some components (controllers, directives, services, etc) after angular.boostrap has been run.

I have looked at Ben Nadel's article on how to do this:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2553-loading-angularjs-components-after-your-application-has-been-bootstrapped.htm

and I can get that working fine.

Now, I find that I want to test this functionality out in Karma/Jasmine/PhantomJS and make sure that my components are working properly after bootstrap, but I'm not quite sure how to create the setup and teardown of that to ensure that angular believes it has already been bootstrapped.

What I have basically been finding out is that when I do the typical angular.mock.module function in the test to retrieve my module, I can continue adding controllers/directives/etc after the fact just fine in Jasmine, even when I haven't rewired the module per instructions from Ben N. that I would need to in order to make it work directly in the browser.

here is a basic example of my code and test:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var module = angular.module('myModule', []);

    // it should not allow adding controllers after bootstrap with the following
    // commented out:

    //module.config(['$controllerProvider', function(controllerProvider) {
    //        module._controller = module.controller;
    //        module.controller = controller;
    //
    //        function controller(name, constructor) {
    //            console.log(name, constructor);
    //            return controllerProvider.register(name, constructor);
    //        }
    //    }]);


}());

describe('lazy module', function() {
    'use strict';

    beforeEach(module('myModule'));

    it('allows controllers to be added after bootstrap', function() {
        angular.module('myModule').controller('mycontroller', [
            '$scope',
            function(vm) {
                vm.add = function add() {
                    vm.sum = vm.a + vm.b;
                }
            }
        ]);
        var $scope= {};
        getController('mycontroller', {$scope:$scope});
        $scope.a = 5;
        $scope.b = 7;
        $scope.add();

        expect($scope.sum).toBe(12);
    });

    function getController(name, model){
        var controller = null;

        inject(function(_$controller_){
            controller = _$controller_(name, model);
        });

        return controller;
    }
});
```

Unless I'm just totally missing something obvious, this test should fail, but it does not.

I'm not sure how to wire things up in Jasmine to make it behave as if the module has already been bootstrapped. Adding the following doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
angular.boostrap(document, ['myModule']);
```

Comment: The [AngularJS bootstrap API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap) warns about this problem.